# Как исправить прерывание речи абонентов?

Tags: телефония, связь

Если они говорят одновременно, прерывание речи длится 1-2 секунду.          Если они говорят не одновременно, прерываний нет.

Comment: Анализировать трафик, загруженость CPU, сети.

Comment: Если настроить опции эхокомпенсации на транковом шлюзе одинаковые для всех sip-интерфейсов, то прерывания исчезли. Но была авария кратковременная на шлюзе, из-за перегрузки процессора шлюза.

Comment: Сеть не загружена трафиком.

Comment: Удалось убрать прерывание речи, выбрав для всех sip-интерфейсов на SMG-1016 параметр эхокомпенсации option2. Но теперь иногда в трубке слышно эхо.